# When I reapply to universities which have previously rejected my applications, do I have to pay application fees again?

Tags: graduate-admissions, application, fees

I applied to a few US universities last year and they rejected my application because of my low GRE scores. Now I want to reapply again to the same universities.  Can you explain the process to reapply?  My concern is about application fees.  Is it required to pay application fees for the second time?

Comment: I don't know, but it's very likely. Application fees are there to cover the cost of processing your application. That cost remains even if you are rejected.

Comment: Hi devika. You may apply for multiple universities at the same time.

Comment: If you haven't gotten improved GRE scores, then applying again is simply going to be a waste of your time and money.

Comment: I edited your question for grammar, punctuation, capitalization, etc.  Please check that it still matches what you want to ask.  I'd recommend that you take more care in writing your application essays than you did for this question!

Comment: I know this doesn't necessarily concern the answer to your question, but as @NateEldredge implied, you need to work harder on improving your language skills otherwise GRE scores will be the least of your worries. Wish you the best of luck.

Answer (score 6):

Generally, there is nothing special about a reapplication; you apply just as if you were applying for the first time.  You will submit all the required materials again.  Of course, you will submit updated transcripts and scores, and you will probably have revised or rewritten your application essay, so you'll submit the updated version.  Letters of recommendation will also need to be resubmitted; you should ask your letter writers to update their letters to reflect whatever you have been doing in the last year.  And yes, you do have to pay another application fee.

Most institutions will give your new application a fresh look; the fact that you have previously applied and been rejected should not prejudice them against your current application.  (However, people are human, and if some of the same people are still on the admission committee, they may have some memories of the weaknesses they saw in your previous application.)

Of course, to have a better chance of acceptance this time, you should have made yourself a stronger applicant!  Hopefully you have better GRE scores and stronger letters of recommendation, and can report some additional helpful and relevant coursework or work experience in the year since your last application.

Comment: Based on what is mentioned clearly on most university admission pages, this is the correct answer. You are practically applying as if for the first time.

Comment: @AbbasJavanJafari Except... hopefully doing a better job.

Comment: I think some universities are cheaper to re-apply to, if they keep their applicants on file then there's less administration work to do in order to update and process the application. I got rejected the first time I applied to my chosen University based on academics, but I don't remember having to pay another fee when I re-applied with a portfolio (BFA degree).

Answer (score 1):

In short? Yes.

Application fees cover the administrative costs of reviewing your application. Every time you apply to these schools, you will need to pay the fees.